# How can I avoid particular string from beginning of all the lines in a file?

Tags: linux

I have a file, the contents are like below,

```
    /hello/dir1/dir2/remove_til_here/code/dira/dir1/a.c
    /hello/dir1/dir2/remove_til_here/code/dirb/dir7/b.c
    /hello/dir1/dir2/remove_til_here/code/dirc/dir3/c.c
    /hello/dir1/dir2/remove_til_here/code/dird/dir2/d.c
    ......
```

I want o/p as below:

```
code/dira/dir1/a.c
code/dirb/dir7/b.c
code/dirc/dir3/c.c
code/dird/dir2/d.c
```

I want to avoid string `/hello/dir1/dir2/remove_stil_here/`from all the line. Please shed some light on this.  I have tried with `cat file | awk '{print $5}'` But it's of no use, 
thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with your `awk` solution: awk uses tab as standard separator. You should set separator to `/` and output everything after fifth separator, not only the fifth column.
Other options are also viable, like `sed`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `sed` ?

```
sed 's|^.*remove_til_here/||'
```

For a non-greedy match I think you can also use perl - no, wait, don't run away:

```
perl -pe 's|^(.*?)remove_til_here/||' file
```

Comment: (+1) Might want to use a non-greedy match though?

Comment: @NPE Does `sed` know about non-greedy matches ? What's the syntax, I always looked for it ?

Comment: wow sed is beautiful!! Thank you cnicutar for you answer!! Thank you :)

Comment: @cnicutar: It looks like you're right. No non-greedy matches in `sed`.

Comment: @NPE In its time-honored tradition, any syntax works in perl, it seems to accept `sed` verbatim (and allows the non-greedy qualifier).

Answer (score 1):

Since the *pattern* to be removed is a *fixed path*, you know how many directory separators are present.  So might as well use `cut`:

```
cut -d/ -f6- inputfile
```